# Can I add properties to an object method?

Tags: javascript

I have a `colors` object to store some constants and want to make `colors.green`, `colors.green.light` and `colors.green.dark` available

I've found plenty of examples of function properties but they don't seem to work for object methods.

This is the syntax I assumed would work:

```js
const colors = {
  green() {
    this.green.lighter = "#3aebc4"
    return "#FFFFFF"
  },
}
```

But `colors.green.lighter` is never defined

Comment: It's defined after you call `colors.green()`, since you're setting that property in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you set for lighter is being scoped to the function `green()`. Unless you execute `green()` the value is never set, but understand that as it's scoped to the green() function, it's not accessible outside that.

See the snippet below:

```js
const colors = {
  green() {
this.green.lighter = "#3aebc4"
return "#FFFFFF";
  },
}
console.log(colors.green());

console.log(colors.green().lighter);
```

Hopefully, that explains function part, but I assume you want an object like:

```
const colors = {
   green: {
      normal: 'green',
      lighter: '#3aebc4',
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can.

Recall that in Javascript, functions/methods are objects too. So you can give them properties.

As what Charlie Schliesser's answer is saying-- you're only defining it after you call colors.green().

You could also

```
colors.green.lighter = "whatever"
colors.green.darker = "whatever 2"
```

Then get the result by

```
colors.green.lighter // whtever
colors.green.darker // whatever 2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const colors={
    green(){
        this.green.lighter='#fff';
        this.green.dark="#000";
        return this;
    }
}
colors.green();
console.log(colors.green.lighter);
```